# header() not working in php when the url contains parameters?

Tags: php, http-headers, redirect, http-redirect

So I'm using `$_GET` to capture the URL to use it later but when I use `$_GET` it wont redirect!

So here's my sample code:
URL : `http://localhost/project/active.php/?s=ieugfshd&h=qwuyrbcq&i=1`

php code:

```
<?php
include 'init.php';
$s = trim($_GET['s']);
$h = trim($_GET['h']);
$i = trim($_GET['i']);
$q = key_check($s,$h,$i);
if($q == 1)
{
header("location:password_active.php");
exit;
}
if($q == 0)
{
header("location:login_failed.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

EDIT:
key_check( ) function

```
function key_check($k1,$k2,$id)
{
$query = mysql_query("select key1 from users where user_id = '$id'");
$key1 =mysql_result($query,0);
$query = mysql_query("select key2 from users where user_id = '$id'");
$key2 =mysql_result($query,0);
$y=strcmp($k1,$key1);
$z=strcmp($k2,$key2);
if($y || $z == 0)
{
return 1;
}
else
{
return 0;
}
}
```

Now when I try this, I got "1" but I'm getting

> This web page has a redirect loop

But my `password_active.php` doesn't have any redirects. It's just an html page.

Comment: i think the problem is $q is neither having 1 nor 0 can you print $q value and check actually what is comming?

Comment: And what the hell is `key_check()`?

Comment: he included a file, maybe it's a function defined in that file?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh: of course it may be defined in that file, the problem here is that the author can't expect us to guess the behavour of his/her functions.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Yeah, I can print and it's showing the correct value according the logic but i can't understand why header( ) is not working!

Comment: @AbraCadaver key_check( ) is just a function which checks with database.

Comment: @harish can you post the source code of that function ? We need to check the return value.

Comment: @BenoitEsnard I just added the function.

Comment: Soo, sad nobody mentioned that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: @VeeeneX But all my previous pages are working fine.

Comment: @harish You are risking [mysql injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @VeeeneX Thanks for your advice! I will take care of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL you're using to access to your script is:

```
http://localhost/project/active.php/?s=ieugfshd&h=qwuyrbcq&i=1
```

This loads `active.php`, which does its role and then tries to send the following header :

```
header("location:password_active.php");
```

The browser recieves this header, and tries to resolve that relative URL by adding `password_active.php` after the last slash before the query string (that `?s=xxx` string).

So your browser loads:

```
http://localhost/project/active.php/password_active.php?s=ieugfshd&h=qwuyrbcq&i=1
```

This loads `active.php` again, which does its role again and then send again the same header, and that loads this page:

```
http://localhost/project/active.php/password_active.php?s=ieugfshd&h=qwuyrbcq&i=1
```

Again. And again. And again. After several tries, your browser understands that something is going wrong and stops.

You should use an absolute URL in your HTTP header:

```
header("Location: /project/password_active.php");
```

Also, please note how HTTP headers should be written, according to the standard.

---

Random notes :

- According to the file names, `$s` and `$h` are both passwords. You should [hash them](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), and not passing them via the URL.
- `if($y || $z == 0)` is unlikely to work as you think, since it will be evaluated as `if y or not z` in pseudo code, while you may have wanted `if not y and not z` for password checking.

Also, good point for calling `exit()` after a `Location` header. You should never forget that, as it is very important and may cause some trouble in your scripts if you forget them.

Comment: It Worked! Thanks man :-).
Good Explanation by the way.

Comment: @harish added some tips to my answer. Not directly related to your problem, but still a good thing to read I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing / after file.php. Like index.php?i=sa